# Which rule or method can be applied against$~\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+6x}-\left(1+3x\right)}{x^{2}}~?$

Tags: limits

$$L:=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+6x}-\left(1+3x\right)}{x^{2}}~~\leftarrow~~\frac{0}{0}~\text{form} \tag{1} $$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(1+6x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1-3x}{x^{2}}\tag{2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{6}{\sqrt{1+6x}}-3}{2x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+6x}}-3}{\frac{2x}{1}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2x}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+6x}}-3\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{3}{2x\sqrt{1+6x}}-\frac{3}{2x}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3}{2x\sqrt{1+6x}}-\frac{3}{2}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$$

$$=\frac{3}{2}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+6x}}-\frac{3}{2}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$$

$$=\frac{3}{2}\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+6x}}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$=\frac{3}{2}\left(\underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}}_{\text{Divergence}}\underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+6x}}}_{=1}-\underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}}_{\text{Divergence}}\right)$$

Stucked. I need your help.

Comment: Wait , I think inf- inf form can be done with some rule or method . Firstly I will remove the term of 1 of convergence at last eqn.

Comment: The book said that as inf-inf form is found, then the form of it can be converted into 0/0 form however that form is as same as the problem statement formula.

Comment: You can multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1+6x}+(1+3x)$. This will give in the numerator $(1+6x)-(1+3x)^2=-9x^2$, which then you can cancel with the $x^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: I will do that operation.

Comment: -9/2 . Got the solution.

Comment: Note that your line 3/4 is also 0/0 form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+6x}-\left(1+3x\right)}{x^{2}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+6x}-\left(1+3x\right)\right)}{x^{2}}\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+6x}+\left(1+3x\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+6x}+\left(1+3x\right)\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(1+6x\right)-\left(1+3x\right)^{2}}{x^{2}\left(\sqrt{1+6x}+\left(1+3x\right)\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+6x-\left(1+6x+9x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}\left(\sqrt{1+6x}+\left(1+3x\right)\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+6x-1-6x-9x^{2}}{x^{2}\left(1+3x+\sqrt{1+6x}\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-9x^{2}}{x^{2}\left(1+3x+\sqrt{1+6x}\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-9}{\left(1+3x+\sqrt{1+6x}\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-9}{\left(1+1\right)}=-\frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: Done the operation.

Answer (score 1):

From your line 4:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+6x}}-3}{2x} \to \dfrac{0}{0}$$

So by L'Hopital's Rule,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+6x}}-3}{2x} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{3}{2(1+6x)^{3/2}}\cdot 6}{2} $$

$$= \dfrac{\frac{-3}{2\cdot(1+6(0))^{3/2}}\cdot 6}{2}=-\dfrac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier when considering $$A=\frac{\sqrt{1+6x}-\left(1+3x\right)}{x^{2}}$$ let
$$\sqrt{1+6x}=y \implies x=\frac{1}{6} \left(y^2-1\right)$$

Replace and simplify to make
$$A=-\frac{18}{(y+1)^2}$$ and now, just compute the value when $y=1$.